# custom hook executed more than once

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I have been struggling with using a custom hook with `useEffect` but sometimes it running more than once, maybe 2 or 3 times but I really have no direction to start with, I know that custom hook may invoke every time the component re-rendered, but I have a flag check inside my hook and an `useEffect` which has a dependency list, why it's still making same call again and again?

```
// custom hook
const useCustomFetch = (startLoad, user) => {
   const hadError = useSelector(state => return state.hadError);
   useEffect(() => {
      // define the async function inside useEffect
      const asyncFetch = async() => {
         const data = await loadingFromApi(user.id, user.emailAddress);
         dispatch(loadwebsite(data)); 
      }

      console.log('useCustomFetch startLoad', startLoad); //I can see two true here
      if(startLoad) {
         asyncFetch();
         dispatch(loadComplete());
      }
   }, [startLoading, dispatch, hadError, loadingFromApi]);
}

// main component
const main = () => {
   const [selectionChanged, setSelectionChanged] = useState(false);
   const [loadData, setLoadData] = useState(false);

   useEffect(() => {
     if(selectionChanged) {
       setLoadData(true); // to trigger custom hook
       setSelectionChanged(false) // to avoid useEffect execute again
     }
   }, [selectionChanged]);
  
   const loadDone = useCustomFetch(loadData, user);

   const selectChange = () => {
     setSelectionChanged(true);
   }
}
```

My idea is that user switch the select dropdown, set my local state of `selectionChanged` to true, which would trigger my useEffect, and useEffect will set my local state of `loadData` to true which would trigger my custom hook.and since I am passing the flag into dependency list of my custom hook, it should execute only once.

But I can see my network has 2 same requests, sometimes 3 same requests, I was wondering if it's because I have 2 setState in my useEffect, but I have to reset the conditional flag and it won't set load data to true again, then why and how should I diagnose such issue?

Comment: You would get better info if you move the `console.log` inside the `if(startLoad)`. logging outside confuses you with # of rerenders

Comment: Thank you, I tried to move it inside `if` statement, but the result are same...I make it outside to detect how many times my custom hook was invoked and how many of them are invoked with `true`, it turns out >=2 times there

Comment: Maybe `hadError` is changing between the 2 calls…